# Proof for $u · v = (u · w_1)(v · w_1) + ... + (u · w_n)(v · w_n)$ - Parseval's identity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

Suppose {**w<sub>1</sub>**, **w<sub>2</sub>**, ... **w<sub>n</sub>**} was an orthonormal basis for R<sup>n</sup> and **u** and **v** were vectors in R<sup>n</sup>.

I'm trying to prove that **u · v** = (**u · w<sub>1</sub>**)(**v ·w<sub>1</sub>**) + ... + (**u · wn<sub>n</sub>**)(**v · w<sub>n</sub>**)

I know that since {**w<sub>1</sub>**, **w<sub>2</sub>**, ... **w<sub>n</sub>**} is an orthonormal basis that spans a subspace that contains **u** and **v**, **u** can be rewritten as

(**u · w<sub>1</sub>**)**w<sub>1</sub>** + (**u · w<sub>2</sub>**)**w<sub>2</sub>** + ... + (**u · w<sub>n</sub>**)**w<sub>n</sub>**

and **v** can be rewritten as

(**v · w<sub>1</sub>**)**w<sub>1</sub>** + (**v · w<sub>2</sub>**)**w<sub>2</sub>** + ... + (**v · w<sub>n</sub>**)**w<sub>n</sub>**

However when I plug in these new values for **u** and **v**, I end up getting

(**u · w<sub>1</sub>**)**w<sub>1</sub>**(**v · w<sub>1</sub>**)**w<sub>1</sub>** + (**u · w<sub>2</sub>**)**w<sub>2</sub>**(**v · w<sub>2</sub>**)**w<sub>2</sub>** + ... + (**u · w<sub>n</sub>**)**w<sub>n</sub>**(**v · w<sub>n</sub>**)**w<sub>n</sub>**

I could try factoring the **w**'s out but that won't lead to the desired result. Perhaps I'm approaching this problem the wrong way? Any feedback is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you defining the product of $\mathbf w_i$ with itself?

Comment: I think that's what I'm having trouble with. All I know is that wi is orthonormal to the other vectors in the basis. Would it be ||wi||^2?

Comment: You were almost there. On the last line, $w_iw_i$ should have been actually $w_i\cdot w_i$.

Comment: I see, but what does w1⋅ w1 equate to?

Comment: Yes, and $\|w_i\|$ should be 1 for your equation to hold. I mean $w_i\cdot w_i=\|w_i\|^2=1$.

Comment: Oh, I now see that it's a unit vector since it's orthonormal. Thank you very much.

Comment: $\mathbf w_i\cdot\mathbf w_i=\|\mathbf w_i\|^2$. You have an orthonormal basis, so what does that mean for this value? BTW, how did the cross terms in $\mathbf w_i\cdot\mathbf w_j$ drop out? If you didn’t forget about them, then you’ve used the definition of orthonormal already.

Comment: Yes, stupid me. I forgot that the length of wi is 1 considering all the vectors in a orthonormal basis are unit vectors. Thank you very much as well. Please forgive my poorly formatted comments and title, I'm still fairly new to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u=\sum_{j=1}^n (u\cdot w_j)w_j$$
$$v=\sum_{k=1}^n (v\cdot w_k)w_k$$
$$u\cdot v=\sum_{jk} (u\cdot w_j)(u\cdot w_k)(w_j\cdot w_k)\\
=\sum_{j=k} (u\cdot w_j)(u\cdot w_k)1+\sum_{j\ne k} (u\cdot w_j)(u\cdot w_k)0\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n (u\cdot w_k)(u\cdot w_k)$$